How do I fix the floating point problem in this case?
I'm trying to make a code for a simple calculator for a programming problem, and I can't figure out how the rounding works in this case.
1 + 0 + 0.0005 returns 1.000 but 2 + 1 + 0.0005 returns 3.001.
Is the problem with how I'm doing the operations?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double res;
    scanf("%lf ", &res);

    char op;
    scanf(" %c", &op);
    double inp;
    scanf("%lf", &inp);

    if (op == '+') {
        res += inp;
    } else if (op == '-') {
        res -= inp;
    } else if (op == '*') {
        res *= inp;
    } else {
        res /= inp;
    }

    scanf(" %c", &op);
    scanf("%lf", &inp);

    if (op == '+') {
        res += inp;
    } else if (op == '-') {
        res -= inp;
    } else if (op == '*') {
        res *= inp;
    } else {
        res /= inp;
    }


    printf("%.3lf\n", res);

    return 0;
}


I don't see how the provided code is related to your problem description. Please provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the problem you are facing

I have edited the code.

Your fix, BTW, if you want to keep using floating-point, is to print less digits and/or increase the accuracy you work with, ie: use "%.2f" and/or add 0.00005. In the long run floating-point is a nightmare to get right!

The format most commonly used for double is IEEE-754 binary64, also called “double precision.” This format uses base two with 53 bits for the significand (the fraction portion of a floating-point representation). In binary64, the closest representable value to 0.0005 is, using binary for the significand, 1.00000110001001001101110100101111000110101001111111002•2−11, which is 0.0005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875.
Floating-point addition produces the mathematical sum of two numbers rounded to fit into the floating-point format. The most common rounding method used is rounding to the nearest representable number, with ties to the choice with the even low digit. The sum of 1 and the number above is 1.0000000000100000110001001001101110100101111000110101001111111002. However, that is more than 53 bits, so, to fit the result in a double, it must be rounded. The bold font here shows the first 53 bits:
1.0000000000100000110001001001101110100101111000110101 001111111002. We see the trailing portion is less than ½ the last digit that fits, so we round down, producing 1.00000000001000001100010010011011101001011110001101012, which is 1.0004999999999999449329379785922355949878692626953125.
When this is rounded to three decimal digits after the decimal point for %.3lf, that formatting rounds down, producing “1.000”.
When we add the number to 3 (in 2 + 1 + 0.0005), the mathematical sum is 11.000000000010000011000100100110111010010111100011010100111111100. Now we have one more digit in the significand, since it starts with “11.” instead of “1.” So the first 53 significand digits are different: 11.000000000010000011000100100110111010010111100011010 100111111100. Now the trailing digits are more than ½ of the last digit that fits, so we round upward, producing 11.000000000010000011000100100110111010010111100011011, which is 3.000500000000000166977542903623543679714202880859375. When this is rounded for %.3lf, it is rounded up, producing “3.001”.
As for what you do to “fix” this, you have not shown any problem it causes other than that the result is not what you expected. The fix for that is to adjust your expectation in light of knowledge of how floating-point works. If the problem is you want to emulate decimal arithmetic instead of using binary arithmetic, then some fixes are available for limited circumstances, but you would need to specify the requirements. In general, binary arithmetic performs binary arithmetic and is not suitable for decimal arithmetic. (Nor will decimal arithmetic eliminate rounding errors; all finite-precision arithmetic is subject to rounding errors.)
